# Verifying $F(A)\subset B$ numerically and symbolically for a complex function $F$ with assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, complex, assumptions

As it is mentioned in a previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155954/664) of mine, one can construct a holomorphic bijection between the (open) unit disc
$D=\{z\in{\bf C}: |z|<1\}$,
and a domain $D\setminus\overline{B_{1/2}(-1/2)}$
where
$B_r(z_0)$ denotes the ball of radius $r$ centered at $z_0$. One of such function is given by
$$
F(z)=g\left(\frac{Log(g^{-1}(z))}{\pi}\right)
$$
where $g(z)=\dfrac{i-z}{i+z}$.

Experiments suggest that $F$ maps the interval $(-1,1)$ to the boundary of the open ball $B_{2/3}(-1/3)$ and one can check numerically by taking sample points from the interval:

```
(*Definition of the function F*)
g[z_] := (I - z)/(I + z);
g1[z_] := InverseFunction[g][z];
F[z_] := g[Log[g1[z]]/Pi];

Rationalize[Abs[F[Range[-0.9, 0.9, 0.1]] + 1/3]]
```

Here is my **question**:

> Can I do this symbolically?

---

The formula Mathematica returns by `Abs[F[x]+1/3]` is
$$
\left| \frac{1}{3}+\frac{i-\frac{\log \left(-\frac{i (x-1)}{x+1}\right)}{\pi }}{\frac{\log \left(-\frac{i (x-1)}{x+1}\right)}{\pi }+i}\right|
$$

Is there way to put a "[constraint](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns.html)" (which shows that $x$ is a real number and $x\in(-1,1)$) to the expression `Abs[F[x]+1/3]` so that it would return the desired number $2/3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define proper [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) in any of these forms:

```
Assuming[
 -1 < x < 1,
 FullSimplify[
  Abs[F[x] + 1/3]
  ]
 ]
(* 2/3 *)
```

Or

```
FullSimplify[
 Abs[F[x] + 1/3]
 , Assumptions -> (-1 < x < 1)
 ]
(* 2/3 *)
```

Or

```
 FullSimplify[
  Abs[F[x] + 1/3]
  , -1 < x < 1
 ]
(* 2/3 *)
```

You can read the documentation about [Assumptions and Domains](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/AssumptionsAndDomains.html)

Comment: You can drop the `Assumptions ->` part for the second solution (and use the `FullSimplify[expr, assum]` form)

Comment: Altho it's more verbose, I prefer the first one to the others; it reads like a sentence to me.