# Simplifying a complex function with assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, complex, assumptions

By experiments, I am expecting that the following complex function

```
G[z_] := I*(1 - z)/(1 + z);
G2[z_] := z/(2 Pi I) - 1;
G3[z_] := -1 - 1/z;
F[z_] := G3[G2[Log[G[z]]]];
```

should work the same as the one in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155998/664), namely, mapping the interval $(-1,1)$ to the boundary of the open ball $B_{2/3}(-1/3)$. I have checked it numerically:

```
Rationalize[Abs[F[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10]] + 1/3]]
```

which gives the desired result $2/3$. But I want to check it symbolically as well and I used the code from this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155999/664):

```
Assuming[-1 < x < 1, FullSimplify[Abs[F[x] + 1/3]]]
```

which gives
[image]

Why does the `Assuming` function not work in this case? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
Assuming[-1 < x < 1,  Abs[F[x] + 1/3] // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify ]
```