# Can this short code be written in terms of `ParametricPlot`?

Tags: graphics, parametric-functions

I'm studying the following short code in an [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155972/664):

```
dphi = Pi/30; (* angle *)
rend = 0.99; (* radius *)
pts = Table[
  r*Exp[I N[phi, 30]], {phi, -Pi + dphi/2, Pi - dphi/2, dphi},
 {r, 0, rend, rend/10}]; (* a table of points in the polar coordinate grid*)

toColor[z_] := List @@ ColorConvert[Hue[Arg[N[z]]/(2 Pi)], "RGB"] 
(* generate colors *)

line[pts_] := line[pts, Identity]; (* define a function using the next one*)

line[pts_, func_] := Line[ReIm[func[pts]], VertexColors -> (toColor /@ pts)]
Graphics[{line /@ pts, line /@ Transpose[pts]}]
```

I can trace line by line to see how the functions `Line[]` and `Graphics[]` work. It looks not very natural and very smart to me.

Can this be translated to a version using `ParametricPlot` instead?

Comment: `ParametricPlot[]` does not have the ability to color mesh lines with a function instead of a solid color. If you're willing to sacrifice that, then yes, this is doable with `ParametricPlot[]`.

Comment: If you really want to use `ParametricPlot[]`, you need to do some work: `Show[Table[ParametricPlot[ReIm[r Exp[I t]], {r, 0, rend}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[Arg[x + I y]/(2 Pi)]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False], {t, -Pi + dphi/2, Pi - dphi/2, dphi}], Table[ParametricPlot[ReIm[r Exp[I t]], {t, -Pi + dphi/2, Pi - dphi/2}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[Arg[x + I y]/(2 Pi)]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False], {r, 0, rend, rend/10}], Axes -> None, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @J.M. many thanks.

Comment: @J.M.: So does your second comment contradict the first one? (Your code works well.)

Comment: The code in the second one is a hack; that is, I generate curves individually and use `Show[]` to bring them all together at the end. So, the two comments are definitely consistent. It's not doable with a single convenient `ParametricPlot[]`, but you can do it with a little work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @J.M.'s comment, I learned that `ParametricPlot` *alone* would not work. One can however do the following:

```
dphi = Pi/30; rend = 0.99; pts = 
 Table[r*Exp[I N[phi, 30]], {phi, -Pi + dphi/2, Pi - dphi/2, 
   dphi}, {r, 0, rend, rend/10}];
Show[
 Table[ParametricPlot[ReIm[r Exp[I t]], {r, 0, rend}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[Arg[x + I y]/(2 Pi)]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False], {t, -Pi + dphi/2, Pi - dphi/2, 
   dphi}], Table[
  ParametricPlot[ReIm[r Exp[I t]], {t, -Pi + dphi/2, Pi - dphi/2}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[Arg[x + I y]/(2 Pi)]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False], {r, 0, rend, rend/10}], 
 Axes -> None, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]