# How can I improve my code for visualizing a complex map?

Tags: plotting, programming, complex

This code visualize a complex map, but it looks rather cumbersome:

```
F[z_] := z^2;
t1 = 0; 
t2 = Pi/3;
r1 = 1;
r2 = 3;
dt = (t2 - t1)/10;
dr = (r2 - r1)/10;

p1 = Show[
  Table[ParametricPlot[ReIm[r Exp[I t]], {r, r1, r2}], {t, t1, t2, 
    dt}],
  Table[ParametricPlot[ReIm[r Exp[I t]], {t, t1, t2}], {r, r1, r2, 
    dr}],
  ParametricPlot[ReIm[r Exp[I 4 dt]], {r, r1 + 5 dr, r1 + 6 dr}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}],
  ParametricPlot[ReIm[r Exp[I 5 dt]], {r, r1 + 5 dr, r1 + 6 dr}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}],
  ParametricPlot[ReIm[r Exp[I 6 dt]], {r, r1 + 6 dr, r1 + 7 dr}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}],
  ParametricPlot[ReIm[r Exp[I 3 dt]], {r, r1 + 6 dr, r1 + 7 dr}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}],
  ParametricPlot[
   ReIm[(r1 + 7 dr) Exp[I t]], {t, t1 + 3 dt, t1 + 6 dt}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}],
  ParametricPlot[
   ReIm[(r1 + 6 dr) Exp[I t]], {t, t1 + 3 dt, t1 + 4 dt}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}],
  ParametricPlot[
   ReIm[(r1 + 6 dr) Exp[I t]], {t, t1 + 5 dt, t1 + 6 dt}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}],
  ParametricPlot[
   ReIm[(r1 + 5 dr) Exp[I t]], {t, t1 + 4 dt, t1 + 5 dt}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}],
  Axes -> None, PlotRange -> All]

p2 = Show[
  Table[ParametricPlot[ReIm[F[r Exp[I t]]], {t, t1, t2}], {r, r1, r2, 
    dr}],
  Table[ParametricPlot[ReIm[F[r Exp[I t]]], {r, r1, r2}], {t, t1, t2, 
    dt}],
  ParametricPlot[ReIm[(r Exp[I 4 dt])^2], {r, r1 + 5 dr, r1 + 6 dr}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}],
  ParametricPlot[ReIm[(r Exp[I 5 dt])^2], {r, r1 + 5 dr, r1 + 6 dr}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}],
  ParametricPlot[ReIm[(r Exp[I 6 dt])^2], {r, r1 + 6 dr, r1 + 7 dr}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}],
  ParametricPlot[ReIm[(r Exp[I 3 dt])^2], {r, r1 + 6 dr, r1 + 7 dr}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}],
  ParametricPlot[
   ReIm[((r1 + 7 dr) Exp[I t])^2], {t, t1 + 3 dt, t1 + 6 dt}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}],
  ParametricPlot[
   ReIm[((r1 + 6 dr) Exp[I t])^2], {t, t1 + 3 dt, t1 + 4 dt}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}],
  ParametricPlot[
   ReIm[((r1 + 6 dr) Exp[I t])^2], {t, t1 + 5 dt, t1 + 6 dt}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}],
  ParametricPlot[
   ReIm[((r1 + 5 dr) Exp[I t])^2], {t, t1 + 4 dt, t1 + 5 dt}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}],
  ImageSize -> 200,
  Axes -> None,
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image] [image]

I'm wondering if there is a way to make it significantly shorter since there are lots of repeating functions used.

Answer (score 10):

You can get filled in grid sectors fairly easily with [`MeshShading`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html):

```
GraphicsRow[
 With[{z = r Exp[I t], col = Black},
    ParametricPlot[ReIm@#[z], {r, r1, r2}, {t, t1, t2}, Mesh -> 9,
     MeshShading -> 
      ArrayPad[{{None, col}, {col, col}, {None, col}}, {{3, 4}, {5, 
         3}}, None], Frame -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
     ]
    ] & /@ {Identity, F}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I didn't expect that it could be this simple. Thanks Michael! I think this should be accepted as an answer to another related question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156339/664.  Do you have a simplification of my code in a way that the T shape would be the same as the one showed in this question?

Comment: @Jack, the only reason why the code for your other question was complicated was that you wanted coloring. Without coloring, it is indeed as easy as Michael has shown.

Answer (score 2):

At least, the generation of the mesh can be shortened to

```
t1 = 0;
t2 = Pi/3;
r1 = 1;
r2 = 3;
ParametricPlot[ReIm[r Exp[I t]], {r, r1, r2}, {t, t1, t2}, 
 Mesh -> {10, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {FaceForm[]},
 MeshStyle -> {{Opacity[.5], ColorData[97][1]}},
 BoundaryStyle -> {{Opacity[.5], ColorData[97][1]}}
 ]
```

[image]