# Can I add different texts to these two pictures using the `If` function?

Tags: conditional

I use the code from [an answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156379/664) to get two pictures:

```
F[z_] := z^2;
t1 = 0; t2 = Pi/3; dt = (t2 - t1)/10;
r1 = 1; r2 = 3; dr = (r2 - r1)/10;

GraphicsRow[
 With[{z = r Exp[I t], col = Black},
    Show[
     ParametricPlot[
      ReIm@#[z], {r, r1, r2}, {t, t1, t2},
      Mesh -> 9,
      MeshShading -> ArrayPad[
        {{None, col}, {col, col}, {None, col}}, {{5, 2}, {4, 4}}, None
        ],
      Frame -> False,
      AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
      PlotRange -> {{-6, 10}, {-1.1, 10}},
      ImageSize -> Medium,
      AxesStyle -> Opacity[0.1]],
     Graphics[{
       {Blue, Circle[], Text[0, {-0.2, -0.3}]},
       {Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {10, 0}}]},
       {Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0}, 10 ReIm@#[ Exp[I Pi/3]]}]}
       }]
     ]
    ] & /@ {Identity, F}]
```

[image]

Can I add *different* texts to these two pictures using the `If` function?

[Added: To clarify my question, I'd like to add the angle symbol `\[Theta]` to the first figure and `2\[Theta]` to the second one. Once I can do this, I'm expecting that I will be able to add other different stuffs to these two figures.]

---

I'm expecting something like `If[#==Identity, Text[\[Theta], {-0.2, -0.3},[]]`, but I don't know the correct syntax: `#==Indentity` does not work.

Comment: Try slipping this into your `Graphics` command:  `{Red, Text[
  If[TrueQ[# == Identity], "Identity", "Not identity"], {1, 2}]}`

Comment: Why exactly is the `If[]` needed? `GraphicsRow[With[(* blah *), Show[(* blub *), PlotLabel -> #]] & /@ {Identity, F}]`.

Comment: @J.M.: I am trying to do different things to those two figures, not only labels.

Comment: "add different texts to these two pictures" sounds confusing, then. What output were you expecting, then?

Comment: @J.M.: yes indeed. I shall edit my question now. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @LouisB: Thank you for your comment! I didn't realize that I should put `If` *inside* `Text[]` and got some error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to LouisB's comment, I can do it with replacing the `Graphics[]` in the code as

```
Graphics[{
  {Blue, Circle[], {FontSize -> 12, 
    Text[If[TrueQ[# == Identity], "\[Theta]", 
      "2\[Theta]"], {.44, .25}]}},
  {Blue, {FontSize -> 16, 
    Text[If[TrueQ[# == Identity], "\[Infinity]", ""], {10.5, 0}]}},
  {Blue, {FontSize -> 16, 
    Text[If[TrueQ[# == Identity], "\[Infinity]", ""], 
     10.5 ReIm@#[ Exp[I Pi/3]]]}},
  {Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {10, 0}}]},
  {Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0}, 10 ReIm@#[ Exp[I Pi/3]]}]}
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `TrueQ[# == Identity]`, use `# === Identity` (or even `MatchQ[#, Identity]`); `==` is intended for *mathematical* equality, and so does not need to evaluate at once, while `===` is a true comparison operator.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm assuming `# === Identity` would be faster than `TrueQ[# == Identity]`?

Comment: ...and less complicated, and using the function intended for that purpose.