# Plotting a complex function under transformation

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, complex

I am trying to plot the unit circle $\vert z\vert=1$ under the transformation $z\to z+\frac1z$ using mathematica.
In general I want to plot a complex function $f(z)$ under the transformation $\phi(z)$.

I tried

```
With[{z=x+I y}, ContourPlot[Norm[z+1/z]==1, {x,-0.75,0.75},{y,-3,3}]]
```

Which does not seem to produce the correct output

Comment: This was a popular question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156339/visualizing-the-complex-map-fz-z2

Comment: Your code produces points `z` on the complex plane such that the absolute value  of `z+1/z` is equal to `1` and so it is a different than the transformation of the uinit circle under mapping `z+1/z`. This answer provides almost the same what you want [Plotting complex numbers as an Argand Diagram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15637/plotting-complex-numbers-as-an-argand-diagram/15643#15643).  First read and then it becomes clear.